# How do I exclude/predefine fields for Index Patterns in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using ELK to monitor REST API servers. Logstash decomposes the URL into a JSON object with fields for query parameters, header params, request duration, headers.

**TLDR**: I want all these fields retained so when I look at a specific message, I can see all the details. But only need a few of them to query and generate reports/visualizations in Kibana.

I've been testing for a few weeks and adding some new fields on the server side. So whenever I do, I need to rescan the index. However the auto-detection now finds 300+ fields and I'm guessing it indexes all of them.

I would like to control it to just index a set of fields as I think the more it detects, the larger the index file gets?

It was about 300MB/day for a week (100-200 fields), and then when I added a new field I needed to refresh, it went to 350 fields; 1 GB/day. After I accidentally deleted the ELK instance yesterday, I redid everything and now the indexes are like 100MB/day so far which is why I got curious.

I found these docs but not sure which one's are relevant or how they relate/need to be put together.

Mapping, index patterns, indices, templates/filebeats/rollup policy

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-lifecycle-management-for-existing-indices/181749/3
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/indices-templates.html

(One has a PUT call that sends a huge JSON text but not sure how you would enter something like that in putty. POSTMAN/JMeter maybe but these need to be executed on the server itself which is just an SSH session, no GUI/text window.)

Comment: You can edit the huge JSON / curl query in text editor and then just copy paste the whole command in SSH session.

Comment: But wouldnt the paste include the line returns, that would immediately run there command but just with the opening {?

Answer (score 0):

To remove fields from your log (since you are using logstash), you can use remove_field option of logstash mutate filter.

Ref: [Mutate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field)

Comment: I still want all fields in the json, but I don't want elastic/Kibana indexing most of them (i.e. url.params.* fields should not be indexed as I will never use these as a search/visualization criteria but when I view a result, I  still want to see those fields and their values)